# Distortion of City -Boundary-Polygons proportional to population size in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, population, cartogram

Is there a way to distort the size of polygons proportional to their population size (as in column in the attribute table)? I want to create a map that looks similar to this:

[image: https://www.bbsr.bund.de/BBSR/DE/Raumentwicklung/RaumentwicklungDeutschland/Projekte/abgehaengte-regionen/abgehaengte_regionen.html]

the cartogram2 plugin works with small datasets, but trying to make the same for all regional units in Germany (around 400)  QGIS crashed with this report:

h2. User Feedback

h2. Report Details

*Crash ID*: a6e72007607c25de38558d32493d43e2f01c1ba4

*Stack Trace*

```
PyInit_sip :
PyInit_sip :
PyFrame_New :
PyObject_Call :
PyInit_sip :
PyInit__core :
PyCFunction_FastCallDict :
PyObject_GenericGetAttr :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyObject_GenericGetAttr :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyErr_Occurred :
PyFunction_FastCallDict :
PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs :
PyObject_Call :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
QMetaObject::activate :
QThread::started :
QThread::start :
BaseThreadInitThunk :
RtlUserThreadStart :
```

*QGIS Info*
QGIS Version: 3.2.1-Bonn
QGIS code revision: commit:1edf372fb8
Compiled against Qt: 5.9.2
Running against Qt: 5.9.2
Compiled against GDAL: 2.2.4
Running against GDAL: 2.2.4

*System Info*
CPU Type: x86_64
Kernel Type: winnt
Kernel Version: 10.0.17134

**Update: When trying a different number of iterations than the default (10) in cartogram3 it works! I tried 5, 8 and 15. All gone well.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `cartogram3` plugin - once installed simply select your layer and press the button.

[image: Cartogram of US States over unmodified layer]

You can then style it like any other layer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ian :) it worked for small datasets, but trying to apply to all regional areas in Germany QGIS keeps crashing

Comment: you'd need to talk to the plugin devs for that I'm afraid